# How to generate tuple in ? operator of pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, apache-pig

My code is as follows

```
temp = foreach requiredData generate (recordType == 3 ? controllingCalledNum : callingPtyNum)as ServiceNumber, (recordType == 3 ? callingPtyNum : controllingCalledNum)as DestinationNumber;
```

Here my code is reduntant..

Can I generate tuple inside '?' operator and do something like this which I can further FLATTERN

```
  temp = foreach requiredData generate (recordType == 3 ? (controllingCalledNum,callingPtyNum) : (callingPtyNum,controllingCalledNum))as (ServiceNumber,DestinationNumber);
```

I am getting error if I try to do like this
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the built-in `TOTUPLE` UDF:

```
temp = foreach requiredData generate FLATTEN(recordType == 3 ? TOTUPLE(controllingCalledNum,callingPtyNum) : TOTUPLE(callingPtyNum,controllingCalledNum))as (ServiceNumber,DestinationNumber);
```

Comment: thanks
but I cant FLATTEN in the same relation here
Caused by: org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.parser.ParseException: Encountered " <FILTEROP> "== "" at line 1, column 57.
Was expecting one of:
    "*" ...

Comment: Try adding more parentheses.  But in any case, if you can't get it to work, you can always `FLATTEN` in a later relation.  The answer to your question is the `TOTUPLE` UDF.